# mapping local file to different name in git repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository and for the moment I excluded a file containing some information (tokens and others that I do not want to share).

I made a copy of it representing a template without the custom information preserving the path.

For example the original one is named `connector.json` and the other `connector_template.json`.

Is it possible to add to the repository the file locally named `connector_template.json` so that on the repository it has the original name `connector.json` but the content of the modified version?